# How to save draft-js editorState data to Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor, draftjs

How to save the Data from draft-js to Meteor?

I'm trying to...

- **save the data from Draft-js to the db**
- **Using React + Meteor**

Here is [Draft.js](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js). Here's a [Meteor starter kit](https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/meteor-react-boilerplate). There's also [this article](https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-how-to-save-editorstate-data-from-draftjs-in-meteor/33326/4) which seems relevant.

But I can't apply the bits of information to the project.

Considering my ~/imports/collections/bins.js to be

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Meteor.methods({
  'bins.insert': function() {
    return Bins.insert({
      createdAt: new Date(),
      content: '',
      sharedWith: [],
      ownerId: this.userId
    });
  },

  'bins.remove': function(bin) {
    return Bins.remove(bin);
  },

  'bins.update': function(bin, content) {
    return Bins.update(bin._id, { $set: { content } });
  }
});

export const Bins = new Mongo.Collection('bins');
```

And considering the guidelines found in [A Beginner’s Guide to Draft JS](https://medium.com/@adrianli/a-beginner-s-guide-to-draft-js-d1823f58d8cc#.1d5nudgqs) to be

```
import React from ‘react’;
import {Editor, EditorState, RichUtils} from ‘draft-js’;
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()};
    this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({editorState});
  }
  _onBoldClick() {
    this.onChange(RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(
      this.state.editorState,
      ‘BOLD’
    ));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id=”content”>
        <h1>Draft.js Editor</h1>
        <button onClick={this._onBoldClick.bind(this)}>Bold</button>
        <div className=”editor”>
          <Editor
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: btw, I wrote a blog post on how to persist draft js data, hope it helps - https://reactrocket.com/post/draft-js-persisting-content/

Comment: @nimrod Thanks, great post.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert `editorState` to raw JS in order to store it in DB:

```
import {
  convertToRaw,
} from 'draft-js';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  // ...
  saveToDb() {
    const contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();

    const rawContent = JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(contentState));

    Meteor.call(/* save rawContent to db */);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Then to convert `rawContent` back to `editorState`:

```
import {
  convertFromRaw,
  EditorState,
} from 'draft-js';

const rawContent = /* get this value from db */;

const contentState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(rawContent));

const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(blocks);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Khang